# How to redirect page when the video is over?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html webpage with a video introduction. I want to redirect it to another webpage, 10 sec after the video is over. I am working mostly with jQuery and HTML.

Comment: I tried to make it with a function in my js file and call this window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"), but it did not work

Comment: please share the html and the js code or try creating a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work. I tried it just now.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){   
   $("#myVideo").bind('ended', function(){
      location.href="http://www.localhost.com";   
   }); 
  });
</script>

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```